# Restore DB2 database from Java code

Tags: java, database, db2

I need to backup and resotre DB2 database from Java code. I can make backup by executing

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('BACKUP DATABASE MY_DB ONLINE TO "/tmp" EXCLUDE LOGS WITHOUT PROMPTING')
```

On the other hand, I have some linux db2 client commands to restore

```
db2 connect to MY_DB; 
db2 quiesce db immediate force connections; 
db2 connect reset;
db2 'RESTORE DATABASE MY_DB ONLINE FROM "/tmp" TAKEN AT 20151223185416 WITHOUT PROMPTING';
db2 ROLLFORWARD DATABASE MY_DB TO END OF LOGS ONLINE;
```

Can I somehow turn it into the stored procedure and call it from java code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to perform a *database-level* recovery operations (`RESTORE` or `ROLLFORWARD`) while the database is online.  Thus, you can't be connected to the database and do this.  You can, however, perform *tablespace-level* recovery operations;  you can restore any tablespace (other than `SYSCATSPACE`) and perform the rollforward operation.

Keep in mind if you are doing this, you could run into minimum-point-in-time recovery issues – the database catalog can't disagree with the state of a tablespace.

Be aware, though, that the `ADMIN_CMD` procedure is not compatible with `RESTORE`, so you won't be able to do this via a JDBC connection to your database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any example of store procedure for recover tablespace?

Comment: Actually, you *can't* execute `RESTORE` via the `ADMIN_CMD` procedure.

Comment: Yes, I've already found topic that says it not supported. So there is no way but restore via linux console?

Comment: Theoretically you could hack together a way to do it with a second database and an some external (`C`) stored procedure, but I'd be more curious about *why* you're trying to do this from an application. `RESTORE` is a fairly low-level operation – not something you would generally do in application code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Restore from java app was part of requirement. But now I can safely say that this is wrong way to go